# How to find SUB-NET for a defined IP Group.?

Tags: python, ip, subnet, nmap, inetaddress

I need to find out how an IP group is divided between subnets inside the network.

For example, I have an IP range `192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255`
and I have to guess how it's divided inside. Maybe they are divided in `/23` or `/24` or few of them are `/22`.

I was trying different ways by using Nmap and netaddr library from python. But so far it seems impossible to get the information.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to detect that from the outside. You can subnet a /16 prefix into /17, /18, /19, ...., /30, or /31 subnets any which way.

Check out [this excellent Q&A](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers) for how subnetting works.